# Python:  Cut and Paste Data on Text File.

Tags: python

I have a text file that contains numbers.

I need to move some of the numbers from the beginning of the file to the end in the correct order.

For example, the Original `TEXT` file has the following content: `0123456789`.

I need to move the **first 4 numbers** to the end in the same order so it'll look like this:

`4567890123.`

Unfortunately i have no idea how to do this with Python,
I don't know even where to start.

Any pointers to solving this problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There are two things you need: 1. (Reading and writing files) http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files 2. (Slicing) http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Answer (score 5):

See the Python tutorial ([section "Strings"](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings); search for "slice notation"):

```
>>> a = "0123456789"
>>> b = a[4:] + a[:4]
>>> b
'4567890123'
```

Or what is it you're really trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

The individual characters of the string `a = '0123456789'` can be accessed through `a[i]`, where for `i=0` you get the character at the first position (indexes are numbered from 0), so `'0'`. You can also extract several characters at once in the form `a[i:j]`, where `i` is the position of the first character and `j` is the position of the character after the last character. If you omit one of `i` or `j`, it will take all characters from the beginning or until the end of the string.

So:

```
a[0] = a[0:1] = a[:1] = '0'
a[1] = a[1:2] = '1'
a[4] = a[4:5] = '4'
a[0:3] = a[:3] = '012'
a[3:5] = '34'
a[4:] = '456789'
```

So the first 4 characters are `a[:4]` and the rest is `a[4:]`. Now you concatenate them together:

```
a[4:] + a[:4]
```

and it will return

```
'4567890123'
```

In order to read the file, you will have to open it in the read mode and use the first line, stripping any whitespace/newlines:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    line = f.readline().strip()
    print(line[4:] + line[:4])
```